# Near Magic Squares with the First 25 Primes

Tags: mathematics, optimization, magic-square

There are 25 primes smaller than 100. What is the closest to a 5 x 5 magic square I can construct with them? By "closest" I mean the one with the most columns, rows, and diagonals (12 in all) adding to the same amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll get things started with

> 10 lines with common sum 215:

> ```
>     23 47 31 43 71
>     89 41 67 11  7
>     13 29 17 97 59
>     53 79  2 61  5
>     37 19 83  3 73
> ```

---

You can achieve

> 12 lines with distinct primes, here with common sum 283:

> ```
>   13 107  79  37  47
>   97  19   7  71  89
>   29  17 131  23  83
>  113   3   5 109  53
>   31 137  61  43  11
> ```

Comment: This is clearly optimal: the row/column containing 2 will have an even sum, all others will have an odd sum.

Comment: Followup: By choosing any 25 primes (not necessarily the 25 smallest), can you achieve 11 or even 12 matching sums?

Comment: @EdMurphy I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeMagicSquare.html